# Comparing a list and a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the fastest way to compare a list and the dict.values in python?
Like for example take these two for instance:

```
dict = {1:'value1', 2:'value2', 3:'value3'}
list = ['val1', 'val2', 'value3']
```

value3 is there in both datastructures, so what would be the fastest way to go through both of them and return the value3. I've tried using forloops but it's too slow.

***Edit***: The Dict is dynamic so every time the code runs the values keep on changing and I get an error like this:

```
unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: `set(list).intersection(dict.values())` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, it would work but  the dict is dynamic and so i get an error of unhashable type: 'set'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not want to use sets you can use a list comprehension:

```
my_dict = {1:'value1', 2:'value2', 3:'value3'}
my_list = ['val1', 'val2', 'value3']


common = [e for e in my_list if e in my_dict.values()]
# ['value3']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `set()` and get the intersection of both ones, also don't use built-in names `dict` and `list` for your variables, one day it'll cause you trouble

```
dict_values = {1:'value1', 2:'value2', 3:'value3'}
list_values = ['val1', 'val2', 'value3']

intersec = set(list_values).intersection(dict_values.values())
print(intersec)
```

---

Without `set`

```
intersec=[]
for value in dict_values.values():
  if value in list_values:
    intersec.append(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make it  work without using sets

Comment: @chadboii_fourtwenty yes iterate in the dict’s values and for each check if it is on the list to keep it

Comment: without set `result = [value for value in dict_values.values() if value in list_values]`